# How to get the same URL every time?

Tags: phpdesktop

I recently found out about PHP Desktop and I want to use it for one of my future apps. However, something I need to make sure is that the URL is *always* the same when the program runs. Sometimes it's 127.0.0.1:56162, sometimes it's 127.0.0.1:62425 or some other random number at the end... how can I make sure the link always stays the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

1. Open the settings.json file
2. Replace the "0" on line 33 (listen_on) to a different port number. The dev recommends a port in the range of 49152–65535.

The "0" is the default value and will actually randomly pick a free port. If you want to have a specific port number every time, you'll have to hard code it there.

[Relevant dev wiki page](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Settings#web_server)